# Как добавить запись в существующую таблицу Excel?

Tags: python, excel

Везде описана запись в новую таблицу, но мне нужна дозапись. Как с параметром "a" в обычных .txt файлах:

```
with open("test.txt", "a") as file:
    file.write("новая запись")
```

Как же всё-таки добавить запись в сушествующую таблицу Еxcel?

Comment: Я бы воспользовался модулем [`openpyxl`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Answer (score 1):

С модулем [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) также просто, например:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

fn = r"C:\temp\test.xlsx"    

wb = load_workbook(fn)    
ws = wb["Sheet1"]    

row = (101, 102, 103)   # <--- новая строка    
ws.append(row)    

wb.save(fn)    
wb.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Способ с пересозданием файла. Считывать xls можно следующей функцией:

```
import xlrd
def extract_sheet(tab_path_, sheet_name_):
    my_book = xlrd.open_workbook(tab_path_)
    my_sheet = my_book.sheet_by_name(sheet_name_)
    return my_sheet
```

Затем превратить таблицу в списки:

```
def xl_to_list(sheet_):
    my_table = []
    for m in range(len(sheet_.col(0))):
        my_row = []
        for n in range(len(sheet_.row(m))):
            my_row.append(sheet_.row(m)[n].value)
        my_table.append(my_row)
    return my_table
```

После можно работать с данными, проводить вычисления и пр., в вашем случае добавить запись, а после сохранить в новую excel:

```
import xlwt
book = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet1 = book.add_sheet(sheet_name_)
sheet1.row(index).write(line)
book.save(export_path)
```